# how to add NEW label to newly added products in opencart

Tags: opencart

Can any one guide me .
how to add **NEW** label to newly added products in category page in opencart ?
or there is any free extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you which OpenCart version use?

Comment: i am using 1.5.6 version of opencart.